# wrong x axis label for time series plot of daily data

Tags: r, time-series

I have 4 years of historical daily data. I plotted time series with command `plot()` and put `xaxt="n"` to customize the x axis. If i want to put daily ticks in the plot and labels for each day, my plot becomes too messy so I wanted to only show ticks for month-years. For example if I have 3 years of data, I only want to put 36 ticks in the x axis each showing the corresponding year and month. I spent a day reading a lot of questions in how to customize x axis but none of the methods worked for my case. I really dont know what else I can do. Here is the code I used:

```
plot(x,xaxt="n")
ticks <- seq.Date(as.Date("2007-01-01"),as.Date("2009-12-31"),"months")
labels <- seq(as.Date("2007-01-01"),as.Date("2009-12-31"),"months")
axis(1,ticks,labels,format="%b%Y")
```

I first used the following code for ticks:

```
ticks<- seq(as.Date("2007-01-01"),as.Date("2009-12-31"),"months")
```

it did not work as ticks should be numeric not characters. I saw [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/no-x-label-using-axis-Date-td4692034.html) that I can use the first code I used but it did not work for my case. I highly appreciate if anybody can give me some hints on that.  Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a representative example or your `dput` for the data set in question

Comment: What is `class(x)`? Is it an `xts` or `zoo` object already, or just a numeric vector?

Answer (score 2):

I can only assume your `x` is a time series, e.g. a `zoo` or `xts` object. If so, you can use the "special" parameters to `plot.xts(...)`. If not, you will have to load the `xts` package, and convert `x` to an `xts` object.

```
# sample data - you have this already??
# historical daily data - SP500
library(quantmod)          # for getSymbols
SP500 <- getSymbols("SP500", src="FRED", auto.assign=FALSE)
class(SP500)               # an xts pbject
# [1] "xts" "zoo"
x <- SP500["2012::2014"]   # ~last 3 years

# you start here ## ASSUMES x is an xts object ##
par(mar=c(3,3,1,1),cex.axis=0.7)
plot(x, major.format="%b-%Y",minor.ticks=FALSE,mgp=c(0,0.5,0))
```

[image]

If you want more control, use `axTicksByTime(...)`

```
# "manual" tick marks
plot(x,xaxt="n")
ticks <- axTicksByTime(x,"months",format.labels="%b-%Y")
axis(1,at = .index(x)[ticks], labels = names(ticks),mgp=c(0,0.5,0))
```

[image]

And a little fancier...

```
# insert line breaks into axis labels
plot(x,xaxt="n")
ticks <- axTicksByTime(x,"months",format.labels="%b-%Y")
axis(1,at = .index(x)[ticks], labels = sub("-","\n",names(ticks)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following may be helpful:

```
> newticks = sapply(strsplit(as.character(ticks), split='-'), function(x) paste(x[1],x[2], sep='_') )
> newticks
 [1] "2007_01" "2007_02" "2007_03" "2007_04" "2007_05" "2007_06" "2007_07" "2007_08" "2007_09" "2007_10" "2007_11" "2007_12"
[13] "2008_01" "2008_02" "2008_03" "2008_04" "2008_05" "2008_06" "2008_07" "2008_08" "2008_09" "2008_10" "2008_11" "2008_12"
[25] "2009_01" "2009_02" "2009_03" "2009_04" "2009_05" "2009_06" "2009_07" "2009_08" "2009_09" "2009_10" "2009_11" "2009_12"
```